# Empty value to system properties in IDEA Run/Debug configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to have "Run" configuration inside IntellJ IDEA with some java system properties predefined (ordinary and easy task). But by some reasons I need to set some properties to empty string -- which is not so easy in IDEA:

```
-Dmy-property=abd
-Dmy-property2=
-Dmy-property3=afd
```

if I enter this in "system properties" input, it will be converted to

```
-Dmy-property=abd
-Dmy-property2=-Dmy-property3=afd
```

IDEA removed "unused" whitespaces. This is not desirable. Currently I can solve this only by moving empty property to th end of list. Is there any other way to enter emtpy property value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see that there is a problem with that.

I created a little test program and it works well even if the properties are *converted*.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-10-24
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String property = System.getProperty("my-property");
        System.out.println("property = " + property);
        String property2 = System.getProperty("my-property2");
        System.out.println("property2 = " + property2);
        String property3 = System.getProperty("my-property3");
        System.out.println("property3 = " + property3);
    }
}
```

And with the following in IntelliJ:

[image]

When running I will get this output:

```
property = abc
property2 = 
property3 = afd
```

The formatted system properties will be correct when you run because the command line will be like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java" -Dmy-property=abc -Dmy-property2= -Dmy-property3=afd <lots of jars> com.stackoverflow.Main
```

I.e. the `-Dmy-property2=` will be empty string.

Comment: You could add `""` as a value to get an empty string if you want it to look better: `-Dmy-property2=""`.